# Include javascript files in a javascript file in a Django project

Tags: javascript, django

I'm using the chart library apexcharts and defined a javascript function for a chart that I'm using multiple times on different parts of the website. The function needs some other scripts to work.
So at the moment, everytime I want to use that function (located in util.js), I have to import the scripts like this in my html template:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="{% static 'shared/js/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "shared/js/apexcharts/dependency2.js" %}"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "shared/js/apexcharts/dependency1.js" %}"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "shared/js/apexcharts/util.js" %}"></script>
```

How can I include the first 3 in my util.js, so that I just have to import util.js?

Answer (score 0):

For importing resources for multiple templates without repeating it's better to have a parent base.html that handle it:

base.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static 'shared/js/apexcharts/apexcharts.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "shared/js/apexcharts/dependency2.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "shared/js/apexcharts/dependency1.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "shared/js/apexcharts/util.js" %}"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
     #your other small page here
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

user_page.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} # extends will add the scripts in header

{% block content %}
   # your content here
{% endblock %}
```

For more, you can read over it at the document: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#templates